# how can i handle post like using real time database in react native?

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to handle user like if he like the post heart icon become red etc.

Here is my DB structure:

[image: Here is the image of my application database]

How can i access Likes field and find current user id, so that on the basis of id i can change like unlike state.

**Here is my like array that contain user id and like status 0 means false**

```
  "likes" : {
"-MgFbI5wXjtjKln1Wkqe" : {
  "aC9dL88GCAXdnGyefY1XDiXd7Iu1" : {
    "like" : 1
  }
},
"-Mgh2-VHK7Ame1RcEs7s" : {
  "Tz3IlnmUvbc0pw9xZCBF1Y42uXo1" : {
    "like" : 0
  },
  "aC9dL88GCAXdnGyefY1XDiXd7Iu1" : {
    "like" : 0
  }
},
```

**i am using flatlist to render all the post but stuck in how can i retrieve these likes and user post in a single array **

Comment: Did you try anything yet? It's much more likely that someone can help if we can see what you've already done. If you haven't tried anything yet, the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) is typically a good place to start, but there are also hundreds of tutorials out there.

Comment: Hi thanks for comments yes i create all the post and counts the user like but didn't get any idea how to change color of heart icon red/black when first time post render

Comment: I really don't have any idea what part of writing the value you're struggling with, so it's unlikely we can explain how to write better than the documentation does. Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, I edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding extra nodes for each like, suggest updating like_counts directly first then insert all uid of users who likes the post.

```
- likes by: -uid1 
            -uid2 
- like_count: 2
```

Or

```
- likes_by: [contains all uid strings (comma separeted) uid1, uid2]
- like_count: 2
```

Both Options are valid but all you have to check that which option will affect more on database read/write limits.